# Windows 10 does not detect Displayport to HDMI connection

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

So I got a new video card (Radeon RX 480) on my 64-bit Windows 10 computer and was pleased, until I tried to plug a second monitor into the Displayport port. It wasn't detected.

Further steps taken:

- I got a Displayport to HDMI cord. No detection.
- I ran Windows Update to see if it detected a need for any drivers. No detection.
- I opened Device Manager to see if I could see any warning or error icons. Nothing.
- I tried `Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Devices and Printers > Add a device` and nothing was detected.

I've read other forum articles that say that Windows 10 hasn't released drivers for Displayport to HDMI cables. In any case, I'm out of ideas.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue and get the second monitor to be detected?

Comment: Passive DisplayPort to HDMI cable only works with [DP++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode) (on display card) to HDMI (on monitor). Also get the latest driver [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

Comment: I already have the latest and correct driver for the video card. The problem is the driver for the cord, which it turns out that MIcrosoft refuses to help with. HP only made drivers for Windows 7, and so now I'll have to contact HP. Oh, the joyous runaound continues.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a `DP to HDMI cord` (as in a passive cable) or do you have a normal active convertor (which may look like a cable but which has electronics build into the cable and often ships with an extra USB cable to server as powersupply for the 'cable'.

Comment: It looks like a single cable without any other components.

Comment: There is no such thing as driver for cable/cord.

Comment: I'm scrapping this line of thought and using dvi to vga as a plan b.

Comment: Why not DVI to HDMI? No signal conversion needed at all (both uses TMDS).

Comment: Actually it make sense to me that passive DP++ to HDMI cable doesn't work on your card. I assume it has three DP ports just like typical RX 480, one HDMI port and one (or two) DVI port. It's probably impossible for it to have five or six TMDS sources anyway. So unless it has some (not so) smart way to route one TMDS source on-demand to one of the DP ports, it is more likely that none of them are DP++. (Personally I would despise it if one or two out of the three ports are DP++ while the other(s) is not)

Comment: Dvi to HDMI is an idea

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this situation is not possible.

To resolve my problem, I had to get a DVI-to-HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

This is very unorthodox, unless someone has an explanation but after a bit of "macgyvering" I got it to work!
Hopefully you can take a bit of info from below to get your setup to work.

The issue I was having with my L246WP monitor and windows 10, was an off centered image.
Read and researched many different posts about similar issues, mostly signal related, over a few days.  Not too much on "off centered images" related to dp++ to HDMI/windows10.

My monitor with ONLY the dp-hdmi cable plugged in, was labelled as a TV Screen and not a digital display, as it is now.
Apparently one of the reasons why windows10 graphics card shifted the image...?!
Most solutions from forums explained modifiying the EDID and .inf etc, a bit too advanced for me and also did not want to mess up my registry on a brand new computer!

Solution; I then came across a CRU (Custom Resolution Utility v1.4.2, used setting 1920x1200 manual) in combination with both VGA and DP++->HDMI cords plugged in.
By leaving both plugged in, my monitor appeared as "digital display."
Also, windows thought I had 2 screens plugged in, so I changed the setting in "Display Settings" to "show only on 1" 
My monitor input setting was also set to RGB (but displaying HDMI!). 
The hdmi input setting showed no signal! So weird, yet the screen was clearly HDMI, with windows and programs opening smoother/faster than on the VGA setting.
Noticeable difference.

Unplugging the VGA cord after setup was complete, also cut the hdmi signal...?
So I had to leave both plugged in.
Opened up the resolution and ratio settings in the "intel graphics settings" program at random, checked on and off the "override" box,  and the image finally filled my screen.
Dont ask me why, but it worked!

Here is a link for the CRU. Download and use at your own risk, I am not responsible for what happens to your computer.  Just know that it worked "A ok" for me!  Its an older version but again, it worked!
https://www.monitortests.com/download/cru/cru-1.4.2.zip

When I restart I sometimes have to go back into the "intel graphics settings" because it shifts left again and play with the resolution and ratio settings. 
I cannot seem to save the screen settings but with a lil patience its quickly fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link for the CRU. Download and use at your own risk, I am not responsible for what happens to your computer. Just know that it worked "A ok" for me! Its an older version but again, it worked! https://www.monitortests.com/download/cru/cru-1.4.2.zip

When I restart I sometimes have to go back into the "intel graphics settings" because it shifts left again and play with the resolution and ratio settings. I cannot seem to save the screen settings but with a lil patience its quickly fixed.